Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
I want to build my Mac app but I cannot because it says "Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code" tho at first building actually worked
It says in the logs:
CodeSign /Users/emicraftnoob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Forge-gfoktvkkktwrqedqszwpzdndemco/Build/Products/Debug/Forge.app (in target 'Forge' from project 'Forge')
    cd /Users/emicraftnoob/xcode/Forge
    
    Signing Identity:     "-"
    
    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --entitlements /Users/emicraftnoob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Forge-gfoktvkkktwrqedqszwpzdndemco/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Forge.build/Debug/Forge.build/Forge.app.xcent --timestamp\=none --generate-entitlement-der /Users/emicraftnoob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Forge-gfoktvkkktwrqedqszwpzdndemco/Build/Products/Debug/Forge.app

/Users/emicraftnoob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Forge-gfoktvkkktwrqedqszwpzdndemco/Build/Products/Debug/Forge.app: code object is not signed at all
In subcomponent: /Users/emicraftnoob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Forge-gfoktvkkktwrqedqszwpzdndemco/Build/Products/Debug/Forge.app/Contents/PlugIns/ForgeTests.xctest
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code

Help
